# Obtaining a json return for html editor in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I'm using the summernotes html form on a FileMaker solution to write emails. originally I had a save button to transfer the html uri into a field and then email that with the client scripts. However, users (and me...) don't like having to click "save" and then "send".

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to automate this. I tried to set the save function on a 1 second recurrence, however, that stops typing and removes the cursor. I'm thinking either someway to pull data via json or ideally some way I can interrogate it with my FileMaker 'send' script?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Editor</title>
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
<!--  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
    var intervalID;
    
    function autoSave() {
        intervalID = setInterval(saveText, 1000);
        }
        
    function saveText() {
                //$('#summernote').summernote('code', 'code');
                    //window.alert('save changes');
                    /* Prep the URL to use for the hand-off to FM. */
                    var fullURL = '[[SAVEURL]]&param=' + encodeURIComponent ($('#summernote').summernote('code'));
                    /* Send the data to FM. */
                    window.location = fullURL;
                    return false;
            }
            
    </script>
</head>


    


<body onload ="autoSave();">
    <div id="summernote">[[CONTENT]]</div>
    <script>

    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 300,
            tabsize: 2,
            toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['style','bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            //['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            //['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            //['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            //['height', ['height']],
            ['insert', ['link']],
            //['insert', ['link','hr','table']],
            //['misc',['codeview']],
            ['mybutton',['save']]
            ],
            buttons: {save: SaveButton}
        });
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the encoded HTML as a parameter in the URL (&param=...) - which causes the page to reload and thus causes the focus to be lost - try passing the parameter as an anchor (#...).

Like that the page won’t reload, and the focus should remain. Of course, you’ll have to adjust your parameter reading code accordingly.

Alternatively, if you have FileMaker 19 you can use the FileMaker.PerformScript or FileMaker.PerformScriptWithOption function to pass the value directly to a script.

Comment: Thanks for the info. FMP17 unfortunately. I'm completely out my depth with html here and wondering if you could give me any pointers on where to search for some reading on the subject?